# Can't share Facebook image post with Cordova Facebook plugin

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, facebook-share

I've created a Cordova/Angular app that pulls a Facebook feed from the api. I'm now trying to add the ability to share one of the Facebook posts on your own timeline. I'm using the Cordova Facebook plugin found here https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

The problem is that when I try to share an image post I just get a "An error occurred. Please try again later" in the Share dialog that appears. I'm not sure how to setup the options to share images properly.

Here's my current code for the share:

```
var options = {
    method: 'share',
    href: post.link,
    caption: post.message
};

$cordovaFacebook.showDialog(options).then(
    function (res) {
        success(res);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        fail(error);
    });
```

Any ideas what the options should be to share an image?

Comment: Include og:image tags on the website that the link points to

Comment: @WizKid Thanks, but I'm sharing a Facebook post so I really have no ability to add tags. I've clarified my description a bit more.